# Is App Detail Required for facebook login if app is not publish?

Tags: android, facebook

I am working an app in which I have implemented Facebook login. I have done login & share  via facebook successfully. But only for debug keystore. Now I want to anyone can login and share with his facebook credential. For that I have to submit all app details and app icon on facebook for his review. Generaly this process for those app which going to publish in android market. But In My case my app is not in any marke, it is in device which have only this app nothing else.Will I have to submit all app details for facebook review by which anyone can login or share via facebook through my app. Please guide me any suggession is very apreciable. If I am not clear comment me not give -ve vote.

Comment: Look @ `Public_Profile (Default)` @ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference. Login does not require you to upload your app for review

Comment: My requirement is not only login, My requirement login as well as share image and video.

Comment: Look at the link those things that are public do not require a review. Facebook is well documented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using only login feature and public data of user, you don't need to submit for review.

As you are looking for any user able to login, this should work by default.

If you using some other feature like, share image/link/data, then you need to submit for facebook review.
For review either send store link of your app or the apk(if not available on store/market).